# Twitter Bootstrap collapse all but first

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I would like to programmatically collapse all but the first item in a Bootstrap 3 collapsible accordion. However, I'm running into some weird behaviour. Please check out this fiddle and let me know what's wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/k9o2j53a/

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var panels = $('#accordion').find('.panel-collapse');
    panels.collapse('hide');
    panels.first().collapse('show');
});
```

When the button is clicked for the first time the behaviour is different than when it is clicked the second time. Subsequent clicks seem to alternate between the desired behaviour and collapsing of every item.

Comment: Try using toggle instead of collapse

Comment: but I don't want to toggle. I want the button to perform the exact same behaviour every time no matter what the current state of the panels is. The user can show/hide each one as desired, but when the button is pressed they should all collapse except for the first. In fact the first should open if it is in a collapsed state when the button is pressed

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#a').click(function(){
   var panels = $('#accordion').find('.panel-collapse').not("#collapseOne");
   panels.collapse('hide');
   panels.collapse('show');
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9o2j53a/1/)

If I understood your question correctly. You want to "collapse all but the first". Pretty straightforward to just use `.not("selector")` to exlude it.

Comment: You understood the question, but this solution doesn't do it exactly. Try pressing the button in your updated fiddle several times. You will see that it alternates between the right behaviour and showing everything. Also, I thought about using the "not" selector or the "first" selector, but this solution may or may not work depending on the initial state of the accordions.

Comment: You're right. Do you want the button to be a `slideUp` only?

Comment: I want the button to have the same behaviour each time it's pressed. That is, no matter what the initial state is of the accordions, the button should collapse them all then show the first.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I was looking for. It turns out that collapsible elements must first be initialized, otherwise the first call to show/hide will perform the initialization itself and cause this 'toggle' behaviour which I've been observing and trying to avoid.

So, to show/hide a panel, it's best to write:

```
$('#accordion').find('.panel-collapse').collapse({toggle: false}).collapse('show');
```

Then to hide all but the first:

```
$('#accordion').find('.panel-collapse:gt(0)').collapse({toggle: false}).collapse('hide');
$('#accordion').find('.panel-collapse:first').collapse({toggle: false}).collapse('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

delay the show so that the hide animation is complete:

```
 $('#a').click(function(){
    $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');

  setTimeout(function(){ $('#collapseOne').collapse('show'); }, 500);

 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k9o2j53a/6/

you can adjust the delay to suit your purposes